# Whatsapp - Python integration

Tags: python, whatsapp

Is it possible to use WhatsApp notification system to receive messages on python?

As for now I'm trying to get the messages using selenium and it's both complicated and unreliable so i was wondering if *maybe* subscribing to something like a websocket could avoid me the selenium part.

Keep in mind that I'm not completely informed on the notification system used on web apps so any suggestion could help

Thanks

Comment: If this is a web site that you control, the selenium is a stupid way to communicate.  You can design a web API that does exactly what you need, sending over information in a convenient JSON format.  If it is not a web site that you control, then you have to use whatever interface they provided.  If they don't have an API, then you're stuck with Selenium.

Comment: The website is web.whatsapp.com and unfortunately i don't control it. And the even bigger problem is that their api (if I'm not wrong) only exists for business members so nope

Comment: There Is a library called Twilio, take a look at that.

Comment: Twilio creates a new number to send and receive messages. I want to use my own